# Why is the running time of two instances on two cores larger than one instance only?

Tags: c++, c

I am facing a "maybe" strange problem. Let's say I have an executable. When I run it on a computer with two cores, the process runs over a time t1. Then, if I run two instances of the process (the same executable but on different directories, launched either manually or by using gnu parallel), the running time for each process is not close to t1 but actually larger, sometimes close to 1.9t1. I must note that the two cores are physical (macbook pro mid 2009, Mountain Lion). I have also tested this behaviour on a linux machine with 8 cores. If I run 1, 2, 3, and 4 instances, the running time per instance is about t1. But, after 5, 6, 7, and 8 instances, the running time per instance is increasingly larger than t1.

I have detected this behaviour when running a simulation. I was able to reduce the test case to the simple test presented below. I wanted to check `std::vector`, `std::array`, static and dynamic arrays, at several compilation levels. The test code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Particle {
private:
  int nc;
public:
  void reset(void) { nc = 0; };
  void set(const int & val) { nc = val; };
};

#define N 10000 // number of particles
#define M 200000 // number of steps

#define STDVECTOR 0
#define STDARRAY  0
#define ARRAY     1
#define DYNARRAY  0

int main (void)
{
#if STDVECTOR
  std::vector<Particle> particles(N);
#elif STDARRAY
  std::array<Particle, N> particles;
#elif ARRAY
  Particle particles[N];
#elif DYNARRAY
  Particle *particles; particles = new Particle [N];
#endif

  int jj = 0;
  for (int ii = 0; ii < M; ++ii) {
    //for (auto & body : particles) body.reset();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx) particles[idx].reset();
    jj = ii;
  }
  particles[0].set(jj*drand48());

  return 0;
}
```

The compilation test is done as

`for a in 0 1 2 3; do printf "\n\nOPT=$a\n\n"; g++-4.8 -O${a} -o tmp.x tmp.cpp; cp tmp.x simul01/ ; cp tmp.x simul02/; time simul01/tmp.x ; parallel 'time {}/tmp.x' ::: simul01 simul02 ; done`

For the two core machine, I obtained the following data:
[image: Running times or one and two processes]

Where the time is in seconds, and, for example, vector-1 or vector-2 means the running time when  using a `std::vector` and running one or two processes, respectively. For the two processes, I took the largest time between the two.

What I expect: I expect the running times for the two processes to be similar to the single process time. But there is a systematic increase in time when more than one instance is running, even if the number of cores is enough. As I said, this also happens for an eight-core machine, when the number of processes is larger than 4.

How I measured the times: I used the `time` command, and choose the user time. The system time is so small that is not enough to explain the difference when one or two processes are running.

I have checked with gcc 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, and 4.9.

Therefore, My question is: Why is this happening? Maybe is related to some intrinsic of the operating system and the migration of processes from core to core. I really do not know. I highly appreciate if someone can shed some light on this because this is affecting the running time of my simulations. I need to run several processes at the same time but the running time is increasing. in contrast, another simulation code with a different method runs in about the same time for both one and two processes. So I want to discard or make sure that this is a problem with my own procedure. I do not know also how to set the processor affinity in a portable way (between mac and linux).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its probably using 1 physical core with hyper-threading. Your Linux example supports this.

Comment: I second Serdalis's thought. How did you verify multiple physical cores? Also make sure you are not starved on some other resource, like memory, or disk I/O bandwidth.

Comment: @Serdalis: I removed all printing, as the example shows, so IMHO there is no I/O bottleneck. The processor is a core 2 duo with two physical cores, no hyper-threading. BUT, I also checked the memory footprint, and although the size is very small, the core 2 duo seems to have a shared L2 cache of 3MB. Do you think this could be the bottleneck?

Comment: Using stdarray and -O3, do a test with M=0 to affirm that the compiler did actually perform the test.

Comment: @MooingDuck In that case the compiler does nothing, the user time is close to zero. The compiler is smart enough to note that it should do nothing at the test shown.

Comment: @iluvatar: I was just concerned since 0.584 is also close to zero.  But if you say it's closer, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your <strike>compiler</strike> CPU might automatically be threading the code. Therefore you would be getting maximum performance with 1 instance... And running 2 instances would therefore take roughly twice the time.

Comment: Compiler will never automatically thread code for you. Doesn't make sense for it to do so. It may parallelize operations within the same context but will never spawn new threads.

Comment: Well okay... Not the compiler, but the CPU. [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/automatic-parallelization-with-intel-compilers)

Comment: CPU only parallelizes instructions as well or two threads with hyperthreading and some other features.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that there are other tasks running alongside your applications (kernel threads, background processes, etc...) On 2 cores introducing another CPU intensive task means there may be thread migration across cores and essentially they are contending for resources. Same is true for the Linux scenario with more cores. Once you reach a certain limit then you will be contending with other processes on the system be it processes you spawned or background processes and kernel threads, etc....

Comment: I agree. I though that reporting only the user time from the `time` command was giving me the actual time running, without counting contentions, etc. For example, sometimes I found the real time to be 7.987secs while the user time was 5.210secs. Do you think that the user time is including those contention times?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things:

1. Core contention - in particular Intel's hyperthreading tends to slow down cpu intensive code that doesn't contain unpredictable jumps. But it could also be that, if you have only two cores, that there is more contention with other processes in the system (network packets, email software waking to check for new mails, etc).
2. Cache contention: If the code and data doesn't all fit in the L1 cache, it may well end up in shared caches, and the two instances fight over who gets to store what and where. Also, if the two threads get scheduled on the same core, because some other process has to run (e.g. your email client, web browser, etc), then L1 cache content gets thrown out from Process A to benefit Process B. It doesn't take that many microseconds to completely fill the replace the content in the L1 cache, so even a very short time will affect this. Chances are also that the second process will be moved across to the other process.
3. Memory bandwith limitations - two instances use twice as much memory bandwidth, causing more load on memory.

The above list is far from a complete list of possibilities, just some of the more common.

You may be able to tell which of these options (or some other) by using a profiling tool, such as `oprofile` or `perf`, and inspect the various performance counters on the machine, comparing the 1 process vs. the 2 process scenario.

Comment: I will test it. I just ran the test with root privileges and high nice and still the behavior persists.

Comment: Priority will only do a little towards preventing other things from making it worse.